# Should names of consoles and other items be edited for capitalization?

Tags: discussion, editing

When editing, should console names/brands have capitalization corrected? Are there correct capitalization (should a list be compiled)?

E.g. should xbox be edited to Xbox or playstation/Playstation to PlayStation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Capitalization is like spelling - if it's wrong, it is wrong. The fact that it's more commonly made a mistake does not make it any less a mistake.

That said, much like tiny punctuation fixes and salutation removal, they're rather minor changes in the scope of revisions. Users with less than 2000 reputation who must suggest edits have a requirement to make at least 6 characters worth of changes to a post - this is to encourage editing more than just one tiny mistake, and instead seeking to address all issues with a post, if not vastly improve it. Otherwise, the reviewers are bogged down with exceptionally minor fixes, often ones that miss the big picture.

As a general rule of thumb, **smaller edits are usually best done within the process of addressing something else with the post**. Be it a retag, a significant information clarification, or even just a slew of capitalizations and spelling fixes, the more substance in the edit, the better.

When you have 2000 reputation, then you can edit these freely without the 6 character restriction. It's still nice to make more substantial edits, but if you run into those scenarios where the only fix is just a singular capitalization, then you're free and able to do it. We do not discourage minor edits from users with at least 2000 reputation because they do not need their edits approved.

Now, if one plans to wage a crusade against a particular capitalization error, then, remember to be mindful of the site traffic. It's wiser to get these kind of errors when they come by into your daily route.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was asking really for when suggesting other edits to include them as well...I wouldn't edit them by themselves

Comment: I'm going to reiterate Grace's last paragraph -- it's bad practice to go "fishing" for edits. If it's on the front page, it's fair game, but don't dive into months-old questions solely for the sake of grammar.